# Normalising data shape in ngrx data store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an application that retrieves tasks associated with a user from Firebase. In the example below, I have retrieved three tasks, but I can't understand why my data shape has come out as below:

[image]

I was hoping that it would look like this:

```
task: [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }]
```

Is it possible to flatten my store as above? This is my code as follows. The mapping happens at `TaskActions.dataReceived`:

```
import * as TaskActions from './task.actions';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ITask } from '../../models/task';

export interface State {
  task: ITask | null;
  error: any;
}

const initialState: ITask = null;

export const taskReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(TaskActions.getData, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.dataReceived, (state, payload) => ({
    ...state,
    tasks: payload.payload ? [ { ...state, ...payload.payload } ] : []
  })),
  on(TaskActions.dataNotReceived, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.signOut, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.signOutSuccess, state => ({ ...state, ...initialState })),
);

export function reducer(state: ITask | undefined, action: Action) {
  return taskReducer(state, action);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the sample of the response received from firebase? I would propose to use `@ngrx/effect` to normalize the data and then dispatch an action to update the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(state, payload) => ({
    ...state,
    tasks: payload.payload ? [ { ...state, ...payload.payload } ] : []
  })
```

This is in practice setting the existing state `tasks` object to a **copy** of the state and **merging** the `payload.payload` object with it.

Did you mean to just add the payload to the `tasks` array? If so you should do this

```
if (payload.payload) {
   return {
      ...state,
      tasks: [...state.tasks,  payload.payload]
   }
}

return state
```